# Default input number value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angularJS and I've just created a simple input box where I want a default value.

Here's the input:

```
<input id="fieldWidth" min="10" type="number"  value="10" ng-model="set.width">
```

However, the value doesn't show as default.

When I try to set it though the scope in the controller

```
$scope.set.width = "10";
```

it says

```
"Cannot set property 'width' of undefined"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you don't need to set the value attribute in your input field. just in your controller do this: $scope.set = { width: 10 };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already... you should set $scope.set before trying to set it's child:

```
$scope.set = {width:10};
```

or

```
$scope.set = {};
$scope.set.width = 10;
```

or you can do without the set object if you don't have other values you are associating with it.

```
$scope.width = 10;
```

`<input id="fieldWidth" min="10" type="number" ng-model="width">`